# How to only filter tag in the new logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, logcat

This new logcat is driving me crazy to see only one message... I need to setup a lot of conditions in order to do so

I have placed a lot of debug logs into my code that I want to see, only those logs since they are in certain order

this is what I did to see it

```
package:app level:debug -tag:MyTestTag
```

Currently I cannot only see that, even changing the tag of the logs, it is also displaying a lot of messages and not what I just want to see

any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add the dash "-" there, it negates the condition. You are basically displaying all logs of debug level that `DON'T` have the `MyTestTag` tag

```
package:app level:debug tag:MyTestTag
```

should work fine